# Delete Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I delete column on index 2 onwards for a dataframe that contains 10 columns. The dataframe looks like this:

```
column1    column2    column3    column4 ...
```

The task is to delete column3-column10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert logic - select first 2 columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, :2]
```

If need [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) select columns names with indexing:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[2:], axis=1)
```

Comment: maybe an `inplace=True` ?

Comment: @JonClements - I prefer assign, [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) ;)

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the link - will have to read through that properly later - not entirely convinced at a first glance I agree with the suggestion there - but thanks for the heads up

Comment: @JonClements - yes, interesting reading. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```py
df.drop(columns=df.columns[2:])
```

`df.drop(columns=[...])`  will drop the provided columns

`df.columns[2:]`  will return the list of columns, `[2:]` selects all columns, starting from the *third* column, all the way to the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
df.iloc[::,0:3]
```

result should be the part you want

Comment: The double `::` will cause an error.